# Center TextView in parent ConstraintLayout but resize based on left/right anchored views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

**I need to have a single-line TextView centered inside it's parent ConstraintLayout, but not overlap other views inside that same layout so that it ads `...` ellipsis at the end**

ConstraintLayout (height: 48dp, width: match_parent) which contains the following 3 child views:

1. Left anchored container (height: 48dp, width:variable - green in the image below)
2. TextView (centered in ConstraintLayout)
3. Right anchored container (height: 48dp, width:variable - blue in the image below)

The left/right containers don't have equal widths (one can be 0 while the other 48dp, or one 48dp and the other 96dp)

[image]

XML layout looks like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="#FF0000">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#00FF00"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/container_start"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/container_end"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="Title Title Title Title" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_end"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#0000FF"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

- If I anchor the TextView to the parent (left/right), it will be centered, but text will overlap side containers
- If I anchor the TextView to the side containers, text won't overlap but then it might not be centered if containers have different widths.

Comment: why are you using `LinearLayouts` on each side of the `TextView`?

Comment: @COYG views will be added in code to those containers. This is the layout of a title bar, so the left/right containers will contain buttons, possibly 1 to the left and 2 to the right, or vice versa

Answer (score 2):

Try my solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="#FF0000">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_start"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#00FF00"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/text_title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/container_start"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/container_end"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="Title Title Title Title" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_end"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#0000FF"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/text_title"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I change width and height to 0dp, because if we constraint sides, we can use it to stretch view.

Then I add `android:gravity="center"` to your TextView. And I also add `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"`

**If you have any questions, let's discuss in the comments**

### Update 1

If you want to implement toolbar in your app, I suggest you to use `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#FF0000">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_arrow_back"
        app:menu="@menu/toolbar_actions">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Toolbar Title TitleTitleTitleTitleTitle"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And menu XML markup

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="action_one"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_android"
        android:title="action 1"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <item android:id="action_two"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_android"
        android:title="action 2"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

Result:

[image]

### Update 2

Try this one, maybe this is what you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="#FF0000">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="Title Title Title Titlsase"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/center_line"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/center_line"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/center_line"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_start"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#00FF00"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/text_title" >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_end"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#0000FF"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="end"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/text_title">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_android"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_android"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical" /> 

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_android"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: lincollincol - same issue. The text is indeed centered, but in the space between container left and container right, no in the entire parent. In this case, if container right is double the size of container left, the text will not be centered in the global layout.

Comment: @CosminRadu You need to display the full text instead of "..."?

Comment: No, I need the TextView to be centered in the parent but show "..." whenever the text gets long enough so that it overlaps a side container.

Comment: @CosminRadu You want to implement toolbar with a back button and 2 other action buttons?

Comment: @CosminRadu Check my update, maybe it helps you . . .

Comment: Thanks for your example, I appreciate it! The problem is I need to implement a custom component, the Toolbar does not offer enough flexibility

Comment: In the Update 2 configuration, if the title is long enough it will span over the side buttons and never add the "..." to trim the text.

Comment: @CosminRadu I think you need to add max length to the title. In this case, it will be adding "..." at the end.

Answer (score 0):

it might be already late, but I had the same problem recently. I solved it by adding guidelines on the left and right layouts and then checking on redraw which one is bigger and setting the begin/end margin to left/right guideline.

The middle layout was constraint to those which meant, it would nicely stay in the middle. If the right layout went more than half, they wouldn't leave any space for the middle layout, so it would remain invisible.

Here is layout:

```
    <!-- Left layout -->

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/left_guide"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="0dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/title_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/right_guide"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/left_guide"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <!-- ... -->
    </LinearLayout>


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/right_guide"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="0dp" />
    
    <!-- Right layout -->
```

I wasn't able to constraint the guidelines to the view, because when I set the `constraintGuide_end` it would be calculated from that view, so I decided to do the rest programmatically.

and code:

```
  fun ToolbarBinding.initKeepTitleInCenter() {
        var leftGuideX = 0
        var rightGuideX = 0

        fun setGuides() {
            val width = root.width
            val max = maxOf(leftGuideX, width - rightGuideX)
            rightGuide.setGuidelineEnd(max)
            leftGuide.setGuidelineBegin(max)
        }

        rightLayout.viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener {
            if (rightGuideX != rightLayout.left) {
                rightGuideX = rightLayout.left
                setGuides()
            }
            true
        }

        leftLayout.viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener {
            if (leftGuideX != leftLayout.right) {
                leftGuideX = leftLayout.right
                setGuides()
            }
            true
        }
    }
```